# How to hide tags from WordPress posts?

Tags: wordpress

When I post an article on my WordPress site then all tags which have used in this post show under the post content. How to hide tags from WordPress posts?

Answer (score 0):

Hook to the 'the_tags' filter and return empty string. Try using the following code:

```
add_filter( 'the_tags', 'remove_the_tags', 10, 5);
function remove_the_tags( $tag_list, $before, $sep, $after, $id ) {
    $tag_list = '';
    return $tag_list;
}
```

Reference:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/the_tags/